# Snap.svg appending to list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I have a list like so:

```
<ul class="legend-list>
  <li id="icon-1"></li>
  <li id="icon-2"></li>
  <li id="icon-3"></li>
  <li id="icon-4"></li>
</ul>
```

And I'm using Snap and an $.each() with JSON data to create a bunch of circles like so:

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
  <circle cx="120" cy="100"></circle>
  <circle cx="140" cy="100"></circle>
  <circle cx="160" cy="100"></circle>
  <circle cx="180" cy="100"></circle>
</svg>
```

I was able to determine that Snap adds an id to all of these which I can grab. It's arbitrary but let's say the pattern is "circ-1", "circ-2", "circ-3", etc etc.

What I'm wondering is how I can grab each of those circles and append them to each list item. I know it's probably something as simple as some sort of loop but I'm losing my marbles thinking about it.

Anyone ever done this before or have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this you can try this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4pdoo8ks/)

Actually i have inserted svg inside every li (as said by @Gudz Daniel) so a new svg is created for each li with new ID and rest is svg plugin code and a Forloop GoodLuck:D

```
<ul class="legend-list" id="demo">
  <li id="icon-1"></li>
  <li id="icon-2"></li>
  <li id="icon-3"></li>
  <li id="icon-4"></li>
</ul>

var demo=jQuery("#demo");
var cnt=demo.find('li').length;
for(var i=0;i<cnt;i++){
     demo.find('li:eq('+i+')').append('<svg id="svg'+i+'"></svg>');
      var s = Snap("#svg"+i);
     var bigCircle=s.circle(100, 100, 50);
    bigCircle.attr({
        fill: "#bada55",
        stroke: "#000",
        strokeWidth: 5
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new SVG Snap objects for each list element, you can't cut circle out of an svg element, so in loop just create snap elements, put there a circle, and this snap object insert into each li element